# Selective Foreign Key Usage in Django (maybe with limit_choices_to argument?)

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm a newbie to Django who just went through the making first app tutorials.
I have a question regarding foreignkey

In models.py
I have two classes called Post and GroupMeeting.
In groupmeetings, there is a foreignkey linking to Post class.
Now, I want GroupMeetings to have only the Post items where
category = 0

In My Implementation, I call all the Post Items.
Is there a way to filter it using limit_choices_to argument or something else?
(I don't quite understand how limit_choices_to argument works...)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    #writerId ...
    CATEGORY = (
        (0, 'MeetingPost'),
        (1, 'AnnounceBoard'),
        (2, 'FreeBoard'),
    )
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(PostTag)
    replies = models.ForeignKey(PostReply)

class GroupMeeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    placeGPS = models.FloatField()
    placeName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dateRepeat= models.ForeignKey(RepeatDays)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit choices for a foreign key, here is how to do it:

```
class GroupMeeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    placeGPS = models.FloatField()
    placeName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dateRepeat= models.ForeignKey(RepeatDays)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, limit_choices_to = {'category': 0})
```

Pretty simple as long as the choices are not context dependent.

Comment: Thank you! it was pretty simple!

Comment: Am I supposed to choose the answer?? If so, i'm not sure how to do it.. My rep is low so I can't upvote it either..

Comment: You can accept by clicking the gray V shaped button under the score of the answer.